# Android View Y Axis Animation

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I am trying to create a mirror reflection of a view, for that I tired the Y axis ObjectAnimator animation using the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
animation.setDuration(3600);
animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

This works perfectly but I want the animation to stop after reaching the desired end position rather than returning back to the original place.

After some research I found that setting the setFillAfter(boolean) method of Animation object to true does that thing.

Now my problem is that i am unable to convert the ObjectAnimator animation to a standard Animation code. to get access to that method.

I realized i could use `RotateAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float pivotX, float pivotY)` to rotate my view and also keep it at the ending place.

But I couldnt figure out what should be the pivotx and pivoty values so that the view stays at the same location and flips around.

Comment: @AHoneyBustard yes but with some other method! i didnt try your method I will post the answer soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually an ObjectAnimator stays at the desired location when the animation ends. Im guessing the line

```
animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
```

is what is making your animation start over and over in an infinite loop, remove this line and you should be fine...